# TextField placeholder and text vertical alignment is not right

Tags: flutter, flutter-text

I am developing a mobile application using Flutter. I am having an issue with aligning the text field's placeholder text and its value vertically centered.

This is my code for TextField.

```
return Container(
      color: Colors.black,
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: TextField(
          onChanged: (text) {
            this.filter = text.toLowerCase();
            this._refreshListItems();
          },
          style: TextStyle(
            height: 0.5
          ),
          cursorColor: Colors.black12,
          textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            filled: true,
            fillColor: Colors.white,
              prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search, color: Colors.black26,),
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                  const Radius.circular(10.0),
                ),
              ),
              hintText: "Search",
            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
              borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                const Radius.circular(10.0),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      )
    );
```

However, when it is rendered, the placeholder and its value are getting a little bit to the top vertically as in the screenshots below.

[image]

[image]

What's wrong with my code and how can I fix it?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `TextStyle(height: 0.5)`? If you remove that it will likely resolve the problem.

Comment: But the height of the TextField become too big.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using text style height to 0.5 is causing the text span to be half of the size of the font size. Remove it as don't think that will help you.

```
style: TextStyle(
    height: 0.5
),
```

In order to handle content size you can play with `contentPadding`

```
decoration: InputDecoration(
   contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(1),
   ....
   ),
```

> I used the following code and it is working

```
contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 8, 0, 0),
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

if you set a custom height, try this.

```
Container(
  height: 36,
  child: TextField(
    maxLines: 1,
    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
    textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      filled: true,
      prefixIcon:
          Icon(Icons.search, color: Theme.of(context).iconTheme.color),
      border: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide.none,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30))),
      fillColor: Theme.of(context).inputDecorationTheme.fillColor,
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      hintText: 'Search',
    ),
  ),
)
```